# How to read files from my directory using a loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file, loops, plot, directory

I have 120 .nc files in my working directory. I need to extract lat, lon, and a percentage variable out of them all to create an animation. I have:

```
percice = ncread('g4.subsetted.NOBM_MON_R2017_ice.20050801.90W_49N_-0E_72N.nc','NOBM_MON_R2017_ice');

lat = ncread('g4.subsetted.NOBM_MON_R2017_ice.20050801.90W_49N_-0E_72N.nc','lat');

lon = ncread('g4.subsetted.NOBM_MON_R2017_ice.20050801.90W_49N_-0E_72N.nc','lon');

imagesc(lon,lat,log10(percice));
```

Then I need to plot the image with imagesc. All my .nc files are the same name except for the date (20050801, 20050901, 20051001, etc.) going up monthly.

How do I use a loop to read the info from the .nc files so I don't need to type out each one individually?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy and straight forward:

```
files = dir('**/*.nc'); %read all files with .nc ending
filename=strcat({files.folder},filesep,{files.name})'; %creates filenames with folder+filename

for i=1:length(filename)
    percice(i) = ncread(filename{i},'NOBM_MON_R2017_ice');
    lat(i) = ncread(filename{i},'lat');
    lon(i) = ncread(filename{i},'lon');
end

imagesc(lon,lat,log10(percice));
```